# Couldnt connect to mysql using hostname

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have server running on Ubuntu 20.04 with mysql 5.7.36. I have strange issue, i couldnt connect to mysql on this server using hostname, for example when i use command: `mysql -u user -h hostname.example -p`
I have error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname.example' (110)

When i try `mysql -u user -h localhost -p` - everything good. But when i use `mysql -u user -h 127.0.0.1 -p` i have same error as above.

Also when i try to connect to mysql server from another server (using hostname), everything good.

In my mysql.conf i have a line `skip-name-resolve`

Adding my resolv.conf (cos i think that i have problem with DNS)

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: *In my mysql.conf i have a line skip-name-resolve* - hence you cannot use mnemonic names (including ones specified in resolv.conf), IP addresses only. Exclusion is `localhost` which is special name distinguished without DNS.

Comment: *when i use `mysql -u user -h 127.0.0.1 -p` i have same error as above.* Looks like network access is disabled, and only socket connections are allowed. Check your settings for `skip_networking` is present.

Comment: @akina i tryed to comment "skip-name-resolve" and restart mysql - its didn't help :(. Also i checked `skip_networing` and i have no such line in my config file. P.s. thanks for helping

Comment: *i have no such line in my config file* Check all config files which may be loaded. Check also the daemon command line for according option. Also check does the server is listening some TCP ports, does it is accessible from another hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in firewall. I checked iptables before, but ufw was enabled